# Hiding some results from UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I'm trying to hide some items that matches certain criteria from a search result.

For example, I'd like to hide all the results for "Sede.idTipoisede=1" which is an attribute in "Sede"

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot,
here is my code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

{
    // cancel any existing search
    [_searchOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];

    // begin new search
    [_searchOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        //NSUInteger length = [searchText length];
        if (![NSString isEmpty:searchText])
        {

        NSArray *filteredTemp = [self.sedi filterMatch:^BOOL(id elem)
                                 {
                                     Sede *sede = (Sede *)elem;
                                     NSArray *split = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

                                     return [sede.nome matchAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.descrizione matchAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.indirizzo matchAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.generi matchAll:split];
                                 }
                                              contains:^BOOL(id elem)
                                 {
                                     Sede *sede = (Sede *)elem;
                                     NSArray *split = [searchText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
                                     return [sede.nome containsAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.descrizione containsAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.indirizzo containsAll:split] ||
                                     [sede.generi containsAll:split];
                                 }];

        // update view on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.filteredItems = filteredTemp;
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        });
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: this question doesn't appear very different from the one you asked [a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711510/how-to-exclude-certain-results-from-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchDisplayController` has two delegate properties, `searchResultsDelegate` and `searchResultsDataSource`, much like the `UITableView`. You should use them to control the filtered table view content.

Comment: I fixed this by acting on the original array that was providing data. Thanks for pointing at a good direction.